# LDAP search in Grafana doesn't work

Tags: authentication, ldap, grafana

I'm struggling for a while to make Grafana LDAP work as I can't find appropriate search filter. In AD, both groups Grafana-Admin/User have a group as a member and that group have users which need to authenticate to Grafana.
To simplify, my user sys22 is in a group called Graylog, group Graylog is a Member Of group Grafana. And, I want to use group Grafana in LDAP configuration.

```
verbose_logging = true                                                                                                    
[[servers]]                                                                                                               
host = "dc-01.corp.domain.com"                                                                                           
port = 389                                                                                                                
use_ssl = false                                                                                                           
ssl_skip_verify = true                                                                                                    

bind_dn = "CN=Grafana-Auth,OU=ApplicationAccount,OU=SE,OU=Admin,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"                             
bind_password = 'pass1'                                                                                            

search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=%s)"                                                                  
search_base_dns = ["dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com"]                                                                              

# group_search_filter = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=%s)"                                                        
# group_search_filter_user_attribute = "distinguishedName"                                                            
# group_search_base_dns = 
["OU=Group,OU=SE,OU=Unit,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"]                                           

[servers.attributes]                                                                                                      
name = "givenName"                                                                                                        
surname = "sn"                                                                                                            
username = "sAMAccountName"                                                                                               
member_of = "distinguisedName"                                                                                            
email = "mail"                                                                                                            

[[servers.group_mappings]]                                                                                                
group_dn = "CN=Grafana- 
Admin,OU=Access,OU=Group,OU=SE,OU=Unit,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"                              
org_role = "Admin"                                                                                                        

[[servers.group_mappings]]                                                                                                
group_dn = "CN=Grafana- 
User,OU=Access,OU=Group,OU=SE,OU=Unit,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com"                               
org_role = "Editor"                                                                                                       

[[servers.group_mappings]]                                                                                                
group_dn = "*"                                                                                                            
org_role = "Viewer"
```

Applying various filters doesn't help and all the time I am getting

```
lvl=eror msg="Invalid username or password" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 
uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
t=2018-05-18T08:01:02+0200 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context 
userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 
remote_addr=X.X.X.X time_ms=13 size=98 
referer=http://graylogprod.corp.domain.com/grafana/login
```

Any advice I'll much appreciate...

Thank you,
B

Comment: Firstly your group search settings are all commented out, so they aren't having any effect at all.  I'd recommend increasing your log verbosity to `debug`, which should give you a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

An issue in my case was in the infrastructure of the AD. Grafana doesn't support nested groups and users couldn't be found.